# How do I turn off the Display Console on my Toyota Corolla LE 2019?

Tags: toyota, corolla, center-console

I have an issue with attention deficit and blinking lights, distracting my driving. How do I turn off the center instrumentation Display console on the 2019 Toyota Corolla LE? I tried going to settings but did not see Display off option. If someone can send me a picture of where the display off button is, that would help.

It says its possible in the user manual "Display off:
A blank screen is displayed", however I cannot locate it.

Thanks,

[image]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to MVM&R. First, good on you for recognizing your needs; most people would have happily driven distracted. Second, this is a branny new car; have you tried calling Toyota and asking? https://www.toyota.com/support/contact-us